# Multiple split on strings

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string of the form:

`s = "1,2;3,4"`

I have to obtain:

`res = [(1,2),(3,4)]`

I could not came up better than:

```
pairs = [pair.split(",") for pair in s.split(";")]
res = [(int(a), int(b)) for a,b in pairs]
```

In fact this doesn't work:

```
>>> res = [(int(a),int(b)) for pair in s.split(";") for a,b in pair.split(",")]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a one-liner solution? What's the most pythonic way to achieve this?
2. Why my latter code doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
>>> [tuple(int(x) for x in i.split(',')) for i in s.split(';')]
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Or with unpacking:

```
>>> [(*(int(x) for x in i.split(',')),) for i in s.split(';')]
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>>
```

Or:

```
>>> [tuple(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in s.split(';')]
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

You could try a list comprehension with `tuple(map(...))` or a nested list comprehension.

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're trying to iterate through a list with two items while you're unpacking it by two iterators. Iteration isn't required for that. To fix your code try:

```
res = [(int(pair.split(',')[0]), int(pair.split(',')[1])) for pair in s.split(";")]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Or:

```
[(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in [pair.split(",") for pair in s.split(";")]]
```

Comment: You can omit the parentheses in the first version. No need to build a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your own approach:

```
[(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in (pair.split(",") for pair in s.split(";"))]
```

Or you can be more concise, using some mapping and unpacking:

```
[(*map(int, p.split(",")),) for p in s.split(";")]
# [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was almost correct, just need to wrap the pair split in an iterable:

```
change
[(int(a),int(b)) for pair in s.split(";") for a,b in pair.split(",")]

to:
[(int(a),int(b)) for pair in s.split(";") for a,b in [pair.split(",")]]
```

Short alternative:

```
[*map(eval, s.split(';'))]
```

(Use `ast.literal_eval` if the data can't be trusted.)